# SCP No such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, scp, superuser

I am trying to extract some .pem certificates files used to encrypt my server but for some reason cannot do it using SCP

I am unable to copy them over to my own machine

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBzYx.png)

[Here are the files in the EC2 instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUosY.png)

[`ls -la` output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXuxV.png)

Not sure why they are showing as red, but after some reading saw that it means they are zipped

Errors when executing SCP command:

```
scp: /home/ec2-user/certificates/fullchain.pem: No such file or directory
scp: /home/ec2-user/certificates/privkey.pem: No such file or directory
scp: /home/ec2-user/certificates/chain.pem: No such file or directory
scp: /home/ec2-user/certificates/cert.pem: No such file or directory
```

**Edit:** Moved to another directory and copied again, set permissions to 777 using

```
sudo chmod 777 -R falltoyourdeathbe.co.uk/
```

but still cannot copy - any ideas? They are still showing as an archive no idea why
[scp still not working on .pem files but fine on readme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCVFG.png)

**Edit 2:** Various commands run to show that there is not a /home/archive directory and that the folder with the certificates now sits under /home/ec2-user/
[image: Another screenshot]

Comment: This is probably a superuser/serverfault question. Can you update your post with the text copied and pasted from your terminal not images.  Also, run `ls -la` so it includes permissions and ownership of the files.

Comment: Hey @mistersmith - updated question with info for you

Comment: Looks like a permission issue..user  `ec2-user` cant access `/home/archive`

Comment: I'm wondering if you're symlinks are not broken. Try `find . -xtype l` in `/home/ec2-user/certificates`. If your `.pem` file appear it means those links are broken. Maybe you moved your files in a different location than `../../archive/falltoyourdeathbe.co.uk/` (or deleted them). Find out where those files went and recreate the links (using `ln -s`).

Comment: @MisterSmith Any ideas??

Comment: or @Fritzip - I have tried changing permissions under a new directory /home/ec2-user/falltyourdeathbe.co.uk ----> .pem files and README here but only the README can be transferred over using SCP

Comment: Its a permissions problem. The pem files live in /home/archive/..., the broken symlinks your seeing are inside /home/ec2-user but they point to files in /home/archive. The user ec2-user needs permission to read the actual files in /home/archive, or you need to move the pem files to a location where ec2-user can access them (somewhere inside /home/ec2-user).

Comment: These files are inside /home/ec2-user because they sit at /home/ec2-user/falltoyourdeathbe.co.uk and I have tried giving the folder 777 permissions but still the same error on the pem files. How do I cd into /home/archive? I cannot even see this directory under /home/ - I will leave another screenshot